# UseEffect doesn't update on json change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, react-hooks

I am developing a language selection app for a survey(for uni). So I have a logger for stuff like objects pressed. This logger updates the json, but the UseEffect doesnt recognize it.

So I have 2 files for this (App.js and Logger.js)
Logger.js:

```
let currentTime = Date.now()
let startTime = Date.now()

export let logingData = {
    "data": {
      "participantLoggingData": {
            "startStudyTime": 0,
            "endStudyTime": 0,
            "studyDuration":0,
            "objectsPressed": [[]]
            }
    }
  }

// Running logging function to check each mouseclick and clicked on elements
Object.keys(window).forEach(key => {
    if (/^on(click)/.test(key)){
        window.addEventListener(key.slice(2), event => {
            //Only track if task is active
            if (true) {
                    if(event.target.className == "Flag"){
                        if(event.target.currentSrc.includes("tn_uk")){
                            logingData.data.participantLoggingData.objectsPressed.push(["English Flag", String((Date.now() - currentTime)/1000)])
                            languageLetter("eng")
                            currentTime = Date.now()
                        }else if(event.target.currentSrc.includes("tn_sp")){
                            logingData.data.participantLoggingData.objectsPressed.push(["Spanish Flag", String((Date.now() - currentTime)/1000)])
                            languageLetter("spa")
                            currentTime = Date.now()
                        }
//more diffrent Flags ...
                    } 


                    if(event.target.className == "languageName"){
                                logingData.data.participantLoggingData.objectsPressed.push([event.target.innerHTML + ' languageName', String((Date.now() - currentTime)/1000)])
                                currentTime = Date.now()                        
                    }

                

                    //Log how long participant spent on total
                    logingData.data.participantLoggingData.endStudyTime = Date.now()
                    logingData.data.participantLoggingData.studyDuration = (Date.now() - startTime)/1000
                 
            }
        },);
    }
})
```

This is my App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './components/Navbar';
import RegionPicker from './components/RegionPicker';
import EuMap from './components/eumap';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'reactjs-popup/dist/index.css';
import { logingData } from './components/Logger';

const App = () => {

  const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:1339/api/participants';
  const [selectedRegion, setSelectedRegion] = useState(null);
  let participantDataID = null;


  const onRegionPickerHandler = (region) => {
    setSelectedRegion(region);
  }

  const clearSelectedRegion = () => {
    setSelectedRegion(null);
  }

  function pauseAnimation() {
    var items = document.querySelector('.circles').childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    }
  }

  function resumeAnimation() {
    var items = document.querySelector('.circles').childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].style.animationPlayState = "running";
    }
  }

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  //console.log(navigate);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("LoginData has changed");
    
  }, [logingData]); // Specify logingData as dependency
  


  return (
          <div className="App">
            <div class="context">
              <NavBar className='nb' clearSelectedRegion={clearSelectedRegion} selectedRegion={selectedRegion} resumeAnimation={resumeAnimation} />
              {selectedRegion ? (
                <div>
                  <EuMap regio={selectedRegion} />
                  {pauseAnimation()}

                </div>
              ) : (
                <div>

                  <RegionPicker onRegionPickerHandler={onRegionPickerHandler} />

                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div class="area" >
              <ul class="circles">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
              </ul>
            </div >
          </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So I know I have more files like eumap, but those work completely fine. I just don't know why the useEffect doesn't recognize any changes made to the logingData.

I tested it with console.log(logingData) inside the logger and indeed it the logindata changed. It seems like app.js has no right to see the data of logindata, eventhough i import it. I also tried to use `logingData.data.participantLoggingData.objectsPressed.length` as useEffect dependency

Comment: Mutating an array doesn't trigger renders or dependency cycles. You would need to pass a new array. Your reliance on direct DOM manipulation is also not very React-ive.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `useEffect` to even *consider* running, the component must be rendering. And the only way to cause the component to render is by setting state (either in `App` itself, or in some parent component). So the first thing we'll need to do is make `loginData` be a state.

And then in order for the effect to *actually* run, loginData must change (since loginData is in the effect's dependency array). React will determine whether it changed by doing an `Object.isEqual` check, which is similar to `===`. It's not checking properties inside the object, it's just checking if it's the same object reference. So if you mutate the state, it will look like nothing has changed, and so the effect will not rerun.

Putting those together, you will do something like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [logingData, setLogingData] = useState({
    data: {
      participantLoggingData: {
        startStudyTime: 0,
        endStudyTime: 0,
        studyDuration: 0,
        objectsPressed: [[]],
      },
    },
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    Object.keys(window).forEach((key) => {
      if (/^on(click)/.test(key)) {
        window.addEventListener(key.slice(2), (event) => {
          //Only track if task is active
          if (true) {
            if (event.target.className == "Flag") {
              if (event.target.currentSrc.includes("tn_uk")) {
                setLogingData(prev => {
                  // Copy the old object at every relevant level, and add new data
                  const next = {
                    ...prev,
                    data: {
                      ...prev.data,
                      participantLoggingData: {
                        ...prev.data.participantLoggingData,
                        objectsPressed: [
                          ...prev.data.participantLoggingData.objectsPressed,
                          ["English Flag", String((Date.now() - currentTime) / 1000)]
                       }      
                    }
                  }
         
                  return next
                });
         // ... Other branches of the if/else will need to set state too    
        });
      }
    });

    // TODO return a teardown function to remove event listeners
  }, []);
```

Depending on what you do with them, `languageLetter` and `currentTime` may need to be states as well.